# by selecting the values in one drop down list based on that selection only values related to that should get in second drop down list

Tags: javascript

```
<td>
  <select name="Country" id="Country">
    <option>select country</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="States" id="States" >
    <option>Select states</option>
    <option>Karnataka</option>
    <option>Maharashtra</option>
    <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
    <option>Tamil Nadu</option>//states of India
    <option>California</option>
    <option>New Jersey</option>
    <option>New York</option>//States of USA
    <option>queens land</option>
    <option>Victoria</option>//States of AUSTRALIA
  </select>
</td>
```

**this is the link were  i wrote my source code. There are different countries list in one drop down option and states list in other drop down option. If user clicks on India in the first drop down list the states related to India should get displayed in second drop down list same with other countries also **
**Please help me to solve this **

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q5d18BcTWwlMCEQD?open=lib%2Fscript.js  this is link for my source code

Comment: Please provide the source code that causes issues in a code block in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of jQuery and data attributes you can achieve this functionality

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Country").change(function() {
          var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

          // Hide all states in States dropdown
          $("#States option").hide();

          // Show all states of selected country
          $("#States option[data-country='" + selectedCountry + "']").show();

          // Show first option 'Select states'
          $("#States option[data-country='Select']").show();

          // Reset States drop down
          $("#States").val('Select states');

        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="form">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="Country" id="Country">
            <option>select country</option>
            <option>India</option>
            <option>USA</option>
            <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="States" id="States">
            <option data-country="Select">Select states</option>
            <option data-country="India">Karnataka</option>
            <option data-country="India">Maharashtra</option>
            <option data-country="India">Uttar Pradesh</option>
            <option data-country="India">Tamil Nadu</option>

            <option data-country="USA">California</option>
            <option data-country="USA">New Jersey</option>
            <option data-country="USA">New York</option>

            <option data-country="AUSTRALIA">queens land</option>
            <option data-country="AUSTRALIA">Victoria</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: if the values for both the dropdowns are getting from database is this same code works???or what is the change to be made plz help me for this

Comment: Of course! You have to set the Value of `Country > Options` and value of `data-country` attribute of  `States > Options` from database.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qjswaRpKKPoRDmKM here is the code where options for the drop down fetching from database so how can i change ur solution to my code

Comment: im very new to coding please help me for this

Comment: i want ur solution of dependable drop down option to work with that code which i have provided what are the changes to be made to that please help me